# webpack-dev-server cannot really compile main.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

[Here](https://github.com/chikadance/test-webpack/tree/webpack-dev-server-cannot-compile) is my project

webpack-dev-server terminal output:

```
Built at: 05/22/2020 6:43:46 PM
                                      Asset       Size  Chunks                               Chunk Names
       8d6d49ad1bd332417f87.hot-update.json   46 bytes          [emitted] [immutable] [hmr]  
    main.8d6d49ad1bd332417f87.hot-update.js  334 bytes    main  [emitted] [immutable] [hmr]  main
main.8d6d49ad1bd332417f87.hot-update.js.map  259 bytes    main  [emitted] [dev]              main
                                    main.js    383 KiB    main  [emitted]                    main
                                main.js.map    434 KiB    main  [emitted] [dev]              main
Entrypoint main = main.js main.8d6d49ad1bd332417f87.hot-update.js main.js.map main.8d6d49ad1bd332417f87.hot-update.js.map
[./src/t.js] 70 bytes {main} [built]
    + 39 hidden modules
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
```

I cannot find the main.js

```
roroco@roroco ~/Downloads/js/test-webpack $ du -ah|grep main.js
4.0K    ./node_modules/os-browserify/main.js
4.0K    ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/lib/utils/createDomain.js
4.0K    ./node_modules/timers-browserify/main.js
12K ./node_modules/sockjs-client/lib/main.js
```

Answer (score 0):

I find the reason:
webpack-dev-server auto refresh code in memory, it doesn't compile code to latest

I don't know why webpack-dev-server doesn't auto compile in my case

but when i change dev-server port:

```
 devServer: {
    port: 3000,
    // contentBase: './',
    // watchOptions: {
    //   poll: true
    // }
  },
```

it fix